# python and assigning variable values in if statements

Tags: python

I'm somewhat of a beginner in python and I swear I got a very similar program to what I'm doing right now to work. But, for some reason, I can't make it work. I was able to pinpoint my problem and created a fake program to play around with it. Here is what the program:

```
global heading
global heading2
global a

heading=2
a=2
heading2=4

def function ():
    if a==2:
        heading=heading2
        print 'yes'
        print heading

function()       
print heading
```

This is what appears:

```
yes
4
2
```

Why doesn't the heading variable heading keep the value 4? I tried putting return heading all over. Didn't work. I tried putting the variables in the parentheses of the function. Didn't work either... Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

`global` statement is meaningless outside of a function. If you want to modify the global variable, instead of introducing a local one, you need to put `global` inside the function

```
def foo():
    global x
    x = x2
```

Also, don't use globals.

Answer (score 3):

The line:

```
    heading=heading2
```

Creates a new *local* variable called `heading`, which is *different* to the other varaible called `heading` that you passed into the function.

You can make the function assign to external variables by adding:

```
global heading
```

before you assign to heading:

```
def function():
    global heading
    if a==2:
        heading=heading2
        print 'yes'
        print heading
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside function, you are creating a local variable called `heading`. This isn't the same `heading` declared outside of the function.